# Text of FormFieldData

Tags: openxml-sdk

I am trying to fill text of FormFieldData in word with open xml
i use this code to get formFieldData list and their FormFieldName from a word document :

```
    var FormFieldDataList= wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FormFieldData>();
foreach (FormFieldData block in x2)
        {
            if (block != null)
            {
                FormFieldName tag = block.ChildElements.OfType<FormFieldName>().ElementAt(0);

            }
        }
```

but i can`t fill their text in doc